# Why does including CodesignKey and CodesignProvision cause ios emulator to crash?

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, csproj

The following section of code is from a Xamarin app for ios. This is in the .csproj file of the project. Building for testing on physical device worked fine, but if the following is included when building for ios emulator, the app crashed after starting up. No errors, no thrown exceptions.

The simulator was being run using Visual Studio on a Mac.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios'))">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <CodesignKey>Apple Development: XXXXXXX </CodesignKey>
    <CodesignProvision>app-name</CodesignProvision>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Once I realized that adding this caused the emulator to crash, I added the conditional IncludeKeys, so that I could

Solution:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios')) and $(IncludeKeys) == true">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <CodesignKey>Apple Development: XXXXXXXX </CodesignKey>
    <CodesignProvision>app-name</CodesignProvision>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because that you don't need a `provisioning profile` to run on the simulator. On the contrary, to test on a physical device, the device must be **provisioned**, and Apple must be informed that the device will be used for testing.

So when deploying your app to a physical device, you need add the following settings in your .csproj file. Meanwhile, you may need to skip below settings when deploying your app to the simulator.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios'))">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <CodesignKey>Apple Development: XXXXXXX </CodesignKey>
    <CodesignProvision>app-name</CodesignProvision>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For more details, you can refer to [Device provisioning for Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/).

Hopefully this clears that up a little bit.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.